# Jenkins CI/CD webhooks issue to connect bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, cicd

we are trying to set up the new Jenkins server and its integration with Bitbucket, We were able to add a webhook to connect to Jenkins from Bitbucket and get 200 response. In Jenkins we have added the bitbucket info to connect to the repository as well.
However while creating the pipeline through git , we are unable to see any pipeline creation.
We are not able to see active pipelines created before that is avaialble in repository though.

Webhook screenshot attached is not available for free now. Pleaes heplp me to choose right plugin to establish the repository connection.
Jenkins CI/CD to connect bitbucket repository to pull all exisitng pipeline and commit new pipelines